# Error in setting up hadoop on Windows 10

Tags: java, hadoop, installation

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Hadoop-2.6.0_on_Windows10.pdf) to setup hadoop on my windows 10. I successfully followed the tutorial till Page 5 and after putting everything I tried to check the `hadoop version` on the command line. But it returns the following error:

```
D:\hadoop-2.6.0\bin>hadoop version
Error: Could not find or load main class Azfar
```

Instead, if I use the following command it somehow works:

```
D:\hadoop-2.6.0\bin>hadoop
Usage: hadoop [--config confdir] COMMAND
where COMMAND is one of:
  fs                   run a generic filesystem user client
  version              print the version
  jar <jar>            run a jar file
  checknative [-a|-h]  check native hadoop and compression libraries availability
  distcp <srcurl> <desturl> copy file or directories recursively
  archive -archiveName NAME -p <parent path> <src>* <dest> create a hadoop archive
  classpath            prints the class path needed to get the
                       Hadoop jar and the required libraries
  credential           interact with credential providers
  key                  manage keys via the KeyProvider
  daemonlog            get/set the log level for each daemon
 or
  CLASSNAME            run the class named CLASSNAME

Most commands print help when invoked w/o parameters.
```

I think it is doing this because my username "Azfar Faizan" contains a space, but I didn't use any path which includes my username folder during setting up. Can anybody guide me where exactly is the problem or I am doing it totally wrong ?